# Locate the code with error when not give in the error descreption

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I get this error in a JSF page, but I can not locate the error in my code to correct it. What can I do if the stack trace do not point to any source code of my own code?

I have not entered or called a value 41.5 and can not find that value on search within the source code as well.

```
WARNING:   StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "41.5"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)
    at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:540)
    at com.sun.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToNumber(ELSupport.java:317)
    at com.sun.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToNumber(ELSupport.java:296)
    at com.sun.el.lang.ELSupport.compare(ELSupport.java:103)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstLessThan.getValue(AstLessThan.java:66)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstAnd.getValue(AstAnd.java:63)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:462)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1850)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.RepeatRenderer.encodeChildren(RepeatRenderer.java:104)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:527)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.encodeChildren(UIRepeat.java:990)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:115)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:70)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:57)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:204)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:121)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:115)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:70)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:57)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:204)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:121)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

JSF Segment that gives rise to error

```
                        <p:panel header="Microbiology"    rendered="#{patientReportController.currentPatientReport.patientInvestigation.investigation.reportType eq 'Microbiology'}" >

                            <p:dataTable id="tblMicVals" value="#{patientReportController.currentPatientReport.patientReportItemOfValueType}"  var="pv"  >

                                <p:column >
                                    <h:outputLabel value="#{pv.investigationItem.name}" rendered="#{pv.investigationItem.ixItemType eq 'Value'}"></h:outputLabel>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column >
                                    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{pv.investigationItem.ixItemType eq 'Value'}">
                                        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{pv.investigationItem.ixItemValueType eq 'Memo'}" >
                                            <p:inputTextarea id="txtMicMemoVal"   style="min-width: 200px;" completeMethod="#{investigationItemValueController.completeValues}"  >
                                            </p:inputTextarea>
                                            <p:watermark  value="#{pv.lobValue}" for="txtMicMemoVal" />
                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{pv.investigationItem.ixItemValueType eq 'Varchar'}">
                                            <p:selectOneMenu id="cmbMicStrVal" value="#{patientReportController.strEnterVal}" editable="true"  style="min-width: 300px!important;" >
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="SENSITIVE" itemValue="SENSITIVE" ></f:selectItem>
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Resistant" itemValue="Resistant" ></f:selectItem>
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Intermediate" itemValue="Intermediate" ></f:selectItem>
                                                <f:ajax event="change"  execute="@this" listener="#{patientReportController.saveStrVal(pv.id) }" ></f:ajax>
                                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                                            <p:watermark  value="#{pv.strValue}" for="cmbMicStrVal" />
                                        </h:panelGroup>


                                    </h:panelGroup>






                                </p:column>
                            </p:dataTable>
                        </p:panel>
```

After the answer by BalusC, which preciously lead me to the place of error, I could identify the cause. As he mentioned, inside expression language, I have used,  ls to compare a string value.

This is the exact place. prv.investigationItem.cssTop is a String. I have used it with lt.

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{prv.investigationItem.ixItemType eq 'Value' and prv.investigationItem.ixItemValueType eq 'Memo' and prv.investigationItem.retired eq false and prv.lobValue ne '' and prv.lobValue ne null and prv.investigationItem.cssTop lt 50 }" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only find the culprit if you're able to carefully read the stack trace. Look closer at the `encodeXxx()` methods which are invoked after `renderView()` method. The class names hints which component/renderer is being processed. Read them from bottom to top in the stack trace.

I've done it for you. Based on the stack trace the culprit is in the following XHTML structure:

```
<p:panel>
    <h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGroup>
            <p:panel>
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <ui:repeat>
                        <x:someComponent rendered="#{??? and ??? lt '41.5'}">
```

This markup is however nowhere visible in the JSF segment you posted. You were thus looking at the wrong place in your XHTML file(s).

Note that `<x:someComponent>` is an unknown component, but most likely a `<h:xxx>` one and that the problem is in its `rendered` attribute which is composed of an `and` (or `&&`) expression whereby the right hand side contains a `lt` (or `<`) equation whereby in turn the right hand side returns `"41.5"` as a `String` instead of a `Long` (note that you can't store decimals in a Long ...) and causing all the trouble.

This should guide you in the right direction as to finding the culprit.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really wonder how could you detect the exact place in my code without even posting the code which contained the error. I have edited and included the lines that gives rice to the error. I was thinking that the variable contains a long value, but in fact it is a string value. Thanks you very much again. You are a genius.

Comment: As said, the class names of the component/renderers are visible in the stack trace. They are easily associated/matched with a specific tag.